# what are the signs that a check disk/disk repair is not working?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, check-disk

I'm trying to understand whether the current state of my Windows 10 PC should be interrupted and force a reboot. I see an arrow cursor on my screen with a black background, and if I move the mouse, the cursor will move also.

My Windows 10 machine froze and needed to be rebooted. It happened twice today, which is somewhat unusual. It prompted me for a checkdisk upon reboot which I accepted. It gets stuck at about 8% or so or then reboots to repeat things again. Once or twice it boots into Windows semi-normally. During those occasions, I could  see the Windows desktop screen, but startup icons didn't load properly and I can't start any program (though I can right click the desktop and see some options. Now I only see the arrow icon on the screen (it's been that way for about 30 minutes).

One complicating factor is that the hard disk is almost full (100 gigs of a 2 TB hard drive). (I haven't had the chance to back up to an external drive). I'm assuming that this will complicate a checkdisk/repair action. Also, I just updated Windows 10 earlier today.

So far the arrow icon with a black background has been on my screen for about 30 minutes. I realize that  I should wait longer, but how do I know that the checkdisk repair is no longer "doing anything."? Should I just wait until the arrow cursor is frozen?

Also, if I were to force a hard reboot and repeat the process, would the time needed to do checkdisk be reduced by how long it was running that process prior to the reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the OS processes are having issues to start correctly.

Please try this:

- Start your system and wait until you get the black screen with only the mouse cursor moving.
- Hit Ctrl + Shift + Escape to get the task manager.
- Once you get the task manager, click on File menu button and select Run New task
- The task to Open is "explorer.exe" and hit OK.

This should force the system to start back up the explorer process and show you your computer desktop.  If so, go ahead and save your data and proceed formatting the HD and installing Windows again.  Don't recommend recover or reparing tools at Windows 10.

If your user desktop didn't come up, look for another computer and save your data putting the HD as an slave in another system via USB with an adapter or SATA cable if there is a Desktop computer.

This happens often after Windows 8 update to Windows 10 without reinstalling or Windows 10 being turned off without advise.

Hope this helps you to find a way to solve your issues.

Regards,

Luis

Comment: fyi I did the latest Win 10 update earlier today....

Comment: I guess my real question is: when you see the arrow cursor with the black background, is it possible that check disk is still running and I need only to wait some more? (Windows warned me that the process will take over an hour)

Comment: @rjnagle Windows 10 updates could also cause this kind of issues.  Depending the configuration (software, hardware) updates may cause the system non responsible.  Did you try the procedures I stated going thru the task manager?

Comment: After reboot and Win login (which I didn't see before), I get arrow cursor and black screen (but no check disk messages). This makes me think that I should give more time for Windows to solve things automatically. Worse comes to worse, I could always start in safe mode and do installation repair. This leads me to assume that it's not a hardware problem but simply a Windows update problem (aggravated by not enough storage space)

Comment: (After swapping keyboards, I see that I can access the Task manager options, so I can do a clean restart. That is encouraging. I think a solution  will come soon.... Will post updates when I fix it.

Comment: Looks like I probably should have taken your advice to load the hd from another machine and backup or delete files.I ended up doing a RESET PC KEEP FILES. In safe/troubleshooting mode

Comment: Ugh, I figured out how to reinstall from the Lenovo Service Partition and encountered another startup problem the first time I tried to reboot. See https://superuser.com/questions/1322587/right-sequence-for-hardening-windows-against-vulnerabilities-that-persist-after